# Store send e-mail in database

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am currently building a support ticket platform in PHP language. (Laravel framework to be exact)

I would like to have the feature that customers can e-mail to a certain e-mail address and that the e-mail gets stored in our database as a ticket itself. ( Or at least calls a url or something with postdata )

How would I go about forwarding e-mails to a PHP url/script or something, can someone get me on track?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably something to do with Email Parser. You will need to "Log in" into an email account (ticket@domain.com) from PHP, read the email, parse it as a ticket and save to your database. I believe you will want something like [this](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the [ImapMailbox](https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap) PHP library to connect to an email inbox, grab the message content, store the data in your database, then delete the email from the inbox.

Alternatively, you could use an external service like [Postmark](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-process-email.html) to receive inbound mail and send your server a webhook for processing in PHP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can send information to server and save message to the db before it will sends. You don't need to post it back to your server, here is some abstract code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $message = $request->get('message');
    $to   = $request->get('to');
    $user = Auth::user();
    Ticket::create(['message' => $message, 'to' => $to->id, 'by' => $user->id]);
    Mail::send('emails.ticket', $message, function($m) use ($to,$user){
        $m->from('app@example.com', 'Your Application');

        $m->to($to->email, $to->name)->subject('Email from user '. $user->name);
    });
}
```

Comment: This wont do I think, if the person lets say mails from gmail, how would I apply this?

Comment: @DennisSmink oh, then you can do a trick with something like mailgun. It can fire an event on incoming messages. Read more here https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-routes.html#actions . It's the best way, if you have VPS, you also can do it by yourself with mail server.

Comment: Gong, he doesn't want to send email out, he wants to parse an email in.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu please, watch my comment. I already know it. No reason for downvoting